# page break after doesn't break page while print

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Actually, what condition needs or when `page-break-after: always` or `before` works ? I tried creating different div for `page-break`, even it doesn't work while changing float, `clear:both`, but doesn't work.

Here four `sections` are in one page. Now I want to **break page** after two section in `print`, but doesn't break, still all remaining. Though `margin-bottom` can be replacement, but it would be better if page-break works

```js
$(document).on('click','#ptn',function(){
  window.print();
})
```

```css
@media print {
  body *{
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  #pay_btn{
    display: none;
  }
  #printDiv, #printDiv * {
      visibility: visible;
   }
   #printDiv {
      width: 297mm;
      height: 210mm;
      position: absolute;
      left:0;
      bottom:0;
      top:0;
      right:0;
   }
   section:nth-child(even) {
    page-break-after: always;
    background:black;
  }
}
#printDiv section{
  width:22%;
  margin-right:5px;
  height:70mm;
  float:left;
  border:2px solid red;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class='col100 txtright'><button id='ptn'>Print</button></div>
  <div id='printDiv'>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use on production today:

In my LESS file

```
@media print {
  .page-break {
    display: block;
    page-break-before: always;
  }

  .no-print {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

And then I have those divs in my code `<div class="page-break"></div>`

They work for me as page breaks. All HTML which goes after this page-break would be on another page when printing